# Magento - Set GrandTotal

Tags: php

I'm using magento 1.9.1

I have a script which is getting the magento session GrandTotal outside the magento system.
I mean i have php file called grandtotal.php and i have placed it to the magento main directory.

Here is the code in grandtotal.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
$app = Mage::app('default'); 
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();

$GrandTotal = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_id)->getGrandTotal();
$HalfTotal = $GrandTotal / 2;

 function SetTotal(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
            $address->setGrandTotal($HalfTotal);
            $address->setBaseGrandTotal($HalfTotal);
            }   



echo "Grand: $GrandTotal<br>Half: $HalfTotal";
?>
```

I'm trying to set the grandtotal but it's not happening.

I'm successfuly getting the grandtotal but i can not set it to something else.

Comment: Where are you calling setTotal? I don't see it being set anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call $address->save() as you arent currently persisting it but this value is calculated on the fly in collectTotals() so dont expect your value to persist too much, next time collectTotals is called it will be overwritten. collectTotals is called from all over magento in cart/checkout.

Comment: This is exactly what i want. Can you please help me with the code? How my code must look like ?

Answer (score 1):

You must override model **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Grand**. In method collect() you can :

```
$address->setGrandTotal(100);
$address->save();
```